# HTML5 Web Storage Cleared when Browser Clear Cache?

Tags: html, web-storage

Is HTML5 Web Storage cleared when the browser clears its cache? If it does, many people like me may lose data if they accidentally clear cache? or like in [this comment](http://www.extjs.com/blog/2010/05/27/the-html5-family-web-storage/#comment-100581) ...

> Since HTML5 local storage is kept separate from js cookies (like Silverlight, Gears, Flash), it opens up a world of 3rd party privacy issues for HTML5 as these objects will likely NOT get deleted with a clear cache or delete temporary data

... where web storage is not cleared, but leads to privacy issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quote the [Mozilla Developer Center](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM:Storage):

> DOM Storage can be cleared via "Tools -> Clear Recent History -> Cookies" when Time range is "Everything" (via nsICookieManager::removeAll)

Note that Flash cookies, OTOH, are quite a bit harder to remove.

Comment: so i guess if i just accidentally press clear cache, i lose my data, but nvm, i guess its same as deleting a file accidentally

Comment: Clearing cookies is different to clearing cache, and it's an important distinction to make.  Clearing cache should only clear things that could be downloaded from the interent anyway.  Clearing cookies could clear local settings.  As a developer I frequently clear the cache to make sure I am using the latest version of my web-applications, however I rarely delete my cookies.

Comment: This only applies to Mozilla based browsers, does it?